# Pointer to pointer of struct field in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    Other_Struct *ptr;
} My_Struct;
```

Lets say I have the pointer `abcd` which its type is `My_Struct`.

How can I get the address of:

```
abcd->ptr
```

?

I mean the address of `ptr` itself (like pointer to pointer) and not the address which is stored in `ptr`.

Comment: Brackets are not necessary. -> has a higher precedence than &.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `&` address of operator, like this

```
Other_Struct **ptrptr = &(abcd->ptr);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
&(abcd->ptr)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, in this scenario you have `My_Struct *abcd` pointing to an address, and what you want is the address of a field inside this structure (it doesn't matter if this field is a pointer or not). The field is `abcd->ptr`, so its address you want is `&abcd->ptr`.

You can easily check this by printing the actual pointer values (the difference between the addresses should give you the offset of `ptr` inside `My_Struct`):

```
struct My_Struct {
    int id;
    void *ptr;
};

main()
{
    struct My_Struct *abcd;
    printf("%p %p\n", abcd, &abcd->ptr);
}
```

**Update:** If you want your code to be portable, standards-compliant, and past and future proof, you may want to add casts to `void *` to the `printf()` arguments, as per @alk's comments below. For correctness, you can also use a standard entry point prototype (`int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`) and, of course, include `stdio.h` to use `printf()`.

Comment: `%p` is defined for `void`-pointers only. So it shall be `printf("%p %p\n", (void*) abcd, (void*) &abcd->ptr);`

Comment: Right, because the size of a pointer can be different depending of what's being pointed to in some platforms. (Typically between code and data -- is there a platform where it varies between different types of data? I thought the void pointer definition was there to prevent usage with `void(*)()`, and usage such as the one above could be considered safe.)

Comment: "*is there a platform where it varies between different types of data*" at least there were, if still in use, I do not know. However, to stick to the Standard my comment stands as is.

Answer (score 1):

The most unambiguous way to do it is thus:

```
My_Struct *abcd;
Other_Struct **pptr;
pptr = &(abcd->ptr);
```

I don't know if the parentheses are really necessary, and I don't care, because it's more readable this way anyway.